# Add search box button in select box jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to add search box button in select(option) box tag in jquery mobile. so is there any attribute for use this things?

Comment: I have answered this on another post. Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40980051/7207222

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery chosen plugin.It have a default search box.And it is simple.
check this site : http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/